# Why not see the CurrentIteration in class ParallelLoopState

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

When I debug the `Parallel.ForEach`, I can find that there is field `CurrentIteration`, but I can't find it from `ParallelLoopState`.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

How to get the value of CurrentIteration?

Comment: If you need the index, why not just use `Parallel.For`?

Answer (score 5):

[`ParallelLoopState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate?view=net-7.0) does not expose this member publicly, you can use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-parallel-foreach-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-action((-0-system-threading-tasks-parallelloopstate-system-int64)))) overload which accepts `Action<TSource,ParallelLoopState,Int64>`:

> It is provided with the following parameters: the current element, `ParallelLoopState`, and **the current element's index** (an `Int64`).

```
Parallel.ForEach(collection, (el, _, index) => ...);
```

Another option would be using `Parallel.For` (if the source collection allows access by index):

```cs
Parallel.For(0, collection.Length, index =>
{
    var current = collection[index];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This property is not `public`. If you are interested for the current iteration, one option is to pass it as part of the data:

```
var indexedSource = source.Select((item, index) => (item, index));

Parallel.ForEach(indexedSource, parallelOptions, entry =>
{
    var (item, index) = entry;
    // Process the item, that has this index.
});
```

In the above example I've used the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) LINQ operator that has a `selector` of type `Func<TSource, int, TResult>`.

A side-effect of using the above technique is that the items will be processed in a roughly ascending order. Which in some cases might be desirable. That's because the LINQ projection hides the identity of the underlying `source`, and prevents the `Parallel.ForEach` from employing specialized range partitioners for sources of type `IList<TSource>` or `TSource[]`.

Comment: _"your only option is to pass it as part of the data"_ - possibly it is not =)

Comment: @GuruStron you are right. I was confused with the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync), that doesn't have overload with index.